# How to change the information in a array

Tags: python

I have these four arrays, and what I'm trying to do is merging the array `TestResults`. like below,

```
 TestResults[0]=TestResults[0]+TestResults[1], TestResults[1]=TestResults[2]+TestResults[3].. and so on.
```

This is because the last for loop insert the wrong `testsuiteNames` in `TestResults`. The arrays is made by scraping a html file, so thats where I have the information from.

Right now the last loop only runs 3 times, and insert testsuiteNames' three text the first three array places in `TestResults`.

```
testsuiteIds=['2900', '2901']
TestIds= [[], [], [], ['2900', '2901'], []]
testsuiteNames=['This testcase we.','GENI', 'Power OFF current target']
TestResults=[[[['Power OFF all nodes', 'passed'], ['Select Target 7 and prepare for flashing it.', 'passed']]], [[['Power ON current target', 'passed'], ['Device Geni Communication Details', 'passed'], ['Delay', 'passed']]], [[['Activate GENI UART 0', 'passed']]], [[['Read Class 2- ID : 0 to 255 small size packet', 'passed'], ['Read Class 4- ID : 0 to 255 small size packet', 'passed'], ['Deactivate GENI UART 0', 'passed']]], [[['Power OFF current target', 'passed'], ['Power OFF all nodes', 'passed']]]]

for testsuiteId,testid in zip(testsuiteIds, TestIds):
    print("\n-----testsuiteId2-----\n",testid)
    print("\n-----testid2-----\n",testsuiteId)
    testid.insert(0,testsuiteId)
    print("\n-----testid22-----\n",testsuiteId)
    print("\n-----testsuiteId22-----\n",testid)

for testsuite,testresult in zip(testsuiteNames,TestResults):
    print("\n-----testsuite2-----\n",testsuite)
    print("\n-----testresult2-----\n",testresult)
    testresult.insert(0, testsuite) #her MSH
    print("\n-----testresult22-----\n",testresult)
```

Expected array:

```
TestResults=[[[['Power OFF all nodes', 'passed'], ['Select Target 7 and prepare for flashing it.', 'passed'], ['Power ON current target', 'passed'], ['Device Geni Communication Details', 'passed'], ['Delay', 'passed']]], [[['Activate GENI UART 0', 'passed'], ['Read Class 2- ID : 0 to 255 small size packet', 'passed'], ['Read Class 4- ID : 0 to 255 small size packet', 'passed'], ['Deactivate GENI UART 0', 'passed']]], [[['Power OFF current target', 'passed'], ['Power OFF all nodes', 'passed']]]]
```

[Link if you want to run code](https://repl.it/@MadsSanderMc/OrchidVisibleAbstracttype)